# Configure elastalert for remote elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

I discover Elastalert and I installed it in my server. In this server there are only Kibana and elastalert install.

When I start Elastalert with the following command :

> elastalert --es_debug_trace ./elastalert.log --rule rulesDIR/MYRULE.yaml

Elastalert start and I can see the request send to Elasticsearch but the host is always "localhost" and my elasticsearch node is on another server...

I set the following configuration :

> rules_folder: rulesDIR
>
> run_every:   seconds: 5
>
> buffer_time:   minutes: 15
>
> es_host: XX.XX.XX.XX
>
> es_port: 9200
>
> writeback_index: elastalert_status
>
> alert_time_limit:   days: 2

When I send the following command : elastalert-create-index``, Elastalert create the index on the good cluster so I don't understand why it call localhost`

Maybe elastalert need to be installed on an elasticsearch node but it's not specified in the documentation...

Someone could help me ?

Best regards,
Clément.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not required to be on the same node.

Please make sure that you are updating the

> es_host and es_port

in the both **config.yaml** and **your_rule.yaml** files.

Comment: Yes i alredy did it... Could you put an example of rules which log the result in file ?

Comment: could you paste the snippet of one of your rule from the rulesDir you have there?